# How to efficiently set one bit at a time in an Erlang binary whithout going imperative?

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, arrays

As an exercise I am working on a parallel implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes. As part of that I am implementing a sequence of bitmaps, using one bit per number to save memory. Reading bits one at a time appear to work fine, but setting them is slow, especially when I use large binaries.

```
getBit(Bin, N, Size)->
    R=Size-N-1,
    <<_:N,Bit:1,_:R>> = Bin,
    Bit.

setBit(Bin, N, Size)->
    R=Size-N-1,
    <<A:N,_:1,B:R>> = Bin,
    <<A:N,1:1,B:R>>.
```

Is there a way to do this well in functional Erlang, perhaps similar to how Arrays work?
I have read about hipe_bifs:bytearray_update but would prefer to keep my coding style functional.

Comment: As long as you are functional, your bitstrings will have to be duplicated every time you change a bit. If you change to other functional data structures, the whole structure does not need to be replicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store your bitmaps as integers (if they are not longer than ~1000 bits):

```
-module(z).
-export([get_bit/2, set_bit/2]).

get_bit(N, B) -> N band bit_to_int(B) > 0.
set_bit(N, B) -> N bor bit_to_int(B).

bit_to_int(B) -> 1 bsl B.
```

---

You might try your version w/o passing the Size, and padding to bytes:

```
getBit(Bin, N)->
    <<_:N/bitstring,Bit:1,_/bitstring>> = Bin,
    Bit.

setBit(Bin, N)->
    <<A:N,_:1,B/bitstring>> = Bin,
    <<A:N,1:1,B>>.

%OR:
setBit(Bin, N)->
    PSize = 8 - ((N + 1) rem 8),
    <<A:N,_:1, Pad:PSize,B/bytes>> = Bin,
    <<A:N,1:1,Pad:PSize,B>>.
```

Can be better or worse :-)

Comment: Doesn't work cause floats can't be big enough.
Changing from using floats to 1 bsl B. It is slightly faster but needs more memory, so I can't store as many bits and is still O(n).
Is still a good idea and might work if Erlang bignums handled powers of two specially. (as Erlang might do while allowing the programmer to use a functional style)

Comment: I receive a _bad argument_ exception when I try to use this implementation of `setBit` (Erlang/OTP 20). Passing it the variable `B` with the value of `<<0:3>>` like so: `setBit(B, 0).` Trying to figure out why and I'm a bit stumped at the moment (I'm very new to this).

Answer (score 2):

Generally one can not do it better then with complexity of `O(log(n))` for both `get` and `set` operations, since Erlang is functional language. You can archive `O(log(n))` using some type of trees. `array`, `dict`, `gb_trees` and `gb_sets` modules does this.

So if you need to make it as fast as possible you have to go imperative - you could try `hipe_bifs` module, process dictionary and `ets` tables.

Comment: Thanks, I found hipe_bifs:bitarray, bitarray_sub and bitarray_update. I guess I have to use those for the sieve and then use it to nudge the developers of Erlang to include the optimization in the system so I can use functional style with efficient execution. Process dictionary I don't see point of here and ets tables are not a good match.